# Aplicação parando quando existem muitos usuários acessando

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, session, iis

Minha aplicação está travando e eu não sei exatamente o motivo. A única coisa que reparo é que quando existem muitos usuários acessando, ou fazendo requisições isso acontece.

Quando ocorre tenho que restartar o pool de aplicativos e levantar a aplicação de novo.

Meu questionamento é: como devo investigar isso?

Não sei como simular muitos usuários acessando.

Answer (score 1):

Podem ser diversos fatores e fica difícil determinar sem conhecer o seu ambiente. O que eu recomendaria fazer é o seguinte:

1. Tente verificar a performance das consultas de sua aplicação e se ela não deixa consultar tabelas grandes inteiramente (Ex: telas de consulta onde você não especifique nada e ela retorna todos os registros da tabela de uma só vez). Várias destas ocorrendo ao mesmo tempo travarão o banco.
2. Verifique se há algum caso onde o banco fique travado (locked) ao inserir ou atualizar uma tabela por muito tempo, pois pode ocorrer de você inserir ou atualizar uma tabela sem commitar ou fazer rollback, executar uma consulta demorada antes de commitar e nesse meio tempo outro usuário tentaria fazer o mesmo processo, travando o banco.
3. Sempre após executar um script da aplicação, certifique-se que a conexão seja 
   fechada antes de encerrá-la. Geralmente o MVC já trata disso, mas em aplicações onde você precisa abrir a conexão manualmente, elas devem ser fechadas ao sair da aplicação, evitando deixar tabelas bloqueadas

Comment: Mais um detalhe, caso você ou alguém use alguma ferramenta para testar o banco (PL/SQL, MYSQL Workbench, etc), verifique se você não deixa alguma tabela bloqueada, esquecendo-se de dar o commit ou rollback em alguma das neste banco

Answer (score -4):

Olá, muito provavelmente as conexões com o seu banco de dados estão sendo abertas e não estão sendo fechadas. Na sua aplicação, fique clicando em vários botões seguidamente, e verás o erro de timeout, e quando dar o erro, verás que o pool de conexões atingiu o tamanho máximo, por isso que quando você restartar a aplicação, todos os usuários conseguem fazer suas atividade, até o processo se repetir de novo

Comment: *"...Na sua aplicação, fique clicando em vários botões seguidamente..."* existem os [testes de carga e de stress](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/248318/137387) que levam a aplicação ao limite de forma profissional e objetiva.