# Qual é a diferença entre um teste de carga e um teste de stress?

Tags: testes, teste-stress, teste-de-carga

[Li aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216574/41056) que o teste de stress é (ênfase minha)

> realizado para submeter o software a **situações extremas**. Basicamente, o teste de stress baseia-se em **testar os limites** do software e avaliar seu comportamento. Assim, avalia-se até quando o software pode ser exigido e quais as falhas (se existirem) decorrentes do teste.

Esse era o mesmo conceito que eu tinha do teste de carga: submeter o software a condições adversas, com muito volume de dados ou seja lá o que for extremo para a cobaia em questão.

[Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244846/como-simular-carga-em-um-banco-de-dados), em que questiono como simular **carga** em um banco de dados, uma das respostas diz que esse tipo de teste é o teste de **stress**. Isso me confundiu mais um pouco e os dois conceitos não estão muito claros para mim.

Os dois testes são sinônimos? O que os difere? Quando utilizar cada teste?

Comment: No meu conceito, um teste de estressa pode ser passar valores extremos para ver se a função retorna correto, então isso não seria um teste de carga...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **Diferença entre teste de carga e teste de stress**

Diferencia-se no que tange ao limite de capacidade de um sistema.

Enquanto o **teste de carga** pretende descobrir qual a capacidade de uso, processamento, acessos etc. de um sistema, o **teste de stress** pretende descobrir em que ponto ele já não aguenta mais funcionar.

Ou se ele apresenta erros antes de chegar nesse limite anteriormente estabelecido, de modo a que sejam realizadas ações de reparo, melhoria, troca de componentes entre outros.

---

- **Definição**

O *teste de carga* é realizado para verificar qual o **volume de transações**, **acessos simultâneos** ou **usuários** que um servidor/software/sistema suporta.

Serve basicamente para medir o volume de carga suportado. Através desse procedimento é possível:

- Analisar a estabilidade de um servidor ou sistema em um período de grande carga de modo a estabelecer um limite de operação;
- Medir o desempenho de um software mediante um grande fluxo de dados e informações;
- Encontrar itens do sistema que podem vir a falhar ou incorrer em erros durante momentos de grande carga;
- Evidenciar como o sistema se comporta enquanto a carga de informações vai aumentando, de modo a verificar lentidão, falhas, bugs etc.
- Fornecer dados e informações para que o sistema/site seja melhorado e otimizado. Entre essas informações, temos o tempo de resposta das páginas;

Por exemplo, no gráfico abaixo vemos o resultado da execução de uma carga de 20 usuários e vemos que o tempo de resposta da página não ultrapassa os 3,5 segundos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

O processo de execução de testes de carga

1. **Definição dos objetivos**

Este é o primeiro passo importante, muitas vezes negligenciado, do teste de carga. Diferentemente de testes funcionais ou de regressão, nos quais resultados de aprovação ou reprovação são definidos, em um teste de carga os resultados são muito menos nítidos e dependem da interpretação para identificar se são bons ou ruins.

Objetivos de teste de carga podem incluir uma ampla variedade de medições, como o tempo de resposta desejado, o número de usuários que cada atividade deve aguentar, o que pode acontecer em momentos de pico, quantidade de usuários móveis suportados, etc.

2. **Configurando um ambiente de teste de carg**a

Um passo muito importante na execução eficiente do teste de carga consiste na criação de um ambiente de teste sólido que replique fielmente o ambiente de produção real. Isso inclui questões relacionadas à configuração e perfis da máquina, arquitetura de rede, balanceadores de carga, firewall, bases de dados, entre outras. Para saber mais sobre este assunto você pode ler nossas dicas para cria um ambiente de teste.

3. **Criação de cenários de carga**

A criação de cenários de carga é feita tanto através dos registros de atividades dos usuários, programação ou, como na maioria dos casos, da combinação dos dois. Cenários de teste de carga incluirão pontos de validação, transações e medições.

4. **Execução de testes**

Uma vez que você tenha configurado os cenários de teste, você os executa usando diferentes condições para simular condições reais com base em seus objetivos. Por exemplo, execute cenários usando diferentes números de usuários de locais diferentes ou usando navegadores diferentes.

5. **Análise dos resultados**

A análise dos resultados depende da interpretação de dados coletados durante a execução do teste. Isso inclui transações de dados, erros, cliques, tempos de resposta das transações, páginas, componentes e medições de desempenho dos servidores.

A grande quantidade de dados coletados é geralmente responsável por tornar a análise de resultados tão desafiadora. O processo de análise é normalmente feito mais de uma vez, pois você deve utilizar configurações diferentes de teste e executar novamente os cenários para evidenciar os problemas e identificar suas origens. Um processo metodológico e bem documentado, planejado e fundamentado em objetivos predefinidos pode economizar muito tempo.

- **Quando é que o teste de carga termina?**

Normalmente um teste de carga termina após a criação de um lançamento, logo antes de colocar o software na produção real. Nos últimos anos, como parte de processos de desenvolvimento ágeis, algumas empresas estão executando seus testes de carga muito mais cedo. Isso permite a identificação e reparo de problemas mais cedo, diminuindo os custos de correção e evitando atrasos de última hora.

Resposta Relacionada: [O que é um teste de stress?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216571/o-que-%C3%A9-um-teste-de-stress/216574#216574)